# Getting the checkbox value via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<?php foreach($active_brand as $brand) { ?>
    <input class="my-checkbox"  value="<?=$brand['id']?>" type="checkbox" <?php if($brand['active']==1) { echo "checked data-toggle='toggle'";} else {echo "data-toggle='toggle' class='off'"; }  ?>>
    <input class="brandActive" id="brandActive" type="hidden" value="<?=$brand['active']?>">
    <?php } ?>
```

I'm trying to access the checkbox value on change function like this in jquery:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.my-checkbox').change(function() {
          /*      var brandStatus = 0;
                if($('.brandActive').val()==0)
                {
                    brandStatus=1;
                }
                else{
                    brandStatus=0;
                }*/
                alert($(this).val()); // this value is ok 
                alert($('.brandActive').val()); // this values => not ok
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The value printed out in:

```
 $('.brandActive').val()
```

is always 0... So I was wondering if I can reach the value of the checkbox somehow within the checkbox itself... There has to be a way I can do this, can someone help me out??

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.my-checkbox').click(function() {
  if(this.checked){
   // do sth
  } else {}
});
```

Comment: Okay this actually worked properly !! :) I've just set the new variable and set its value to 1 if the checkbox is checked, if not , I just set the value to the 0 and pass it into the action ... Thanks !!!

Comment: @Grisza Just a note doing this is much more efficient: `if(this.checked) {` as `this` is the native checkbox element rather than going through the jquery api

Answer (score -1):

You never update the value of your `input type hidden`.

Add this at the beginning of your `change` event handler:

```
$(this).next().val($(this).val());
```

Comment: Never going to work as there are multiple elements you can see the php loop.